# Integer division by zero c++

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that inputs a number and outputs the highest divisor of it and then the highest divisor of the divisor and so on, until it reaches a prime. But I keep geting :
"Unhandled exception at 0x00eb1504 in primefinder.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero."

I guess its the "num%i" that causes it but "i" can't be zero since its "num/2".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int i=666, num;
    cout << "Enter number";
    cin >> num;
    while(i>1){
        i = num/2;
        while(num % i == 0){
            i--;
        }
        cout << i << endl;
        num=i;
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check what `num` is to start with? If that comes out as zero, then `i` is zero, and you're doing division by zero for your `%` modulo operation, and boom goes your error.

Comment: If `num` becomes 1 then `num/2` will be zero (by integer division).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ooga mentions in his comment, 1/2 (and 0/2) will equal zero due to integer math.

To avoid division by 0 here, change `cin >> num;` to:

```
do
{
    cin >> num;
} while (num <= 1);
```

This will continue prompting until a valid number is input.

**EDIT:** [Cornstalk's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805028/1730078) properly points out that you must guard the inner-most while loop with `i > 0 && num % i == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

If `i` is zero, then `num % i` can result in this error. When can this happen? Let's say you put the number 2 as input. Then it executes as:

```
    i = num/2; // i is now (2 / 2) = 1
    while(num % i == 0){ // 2 % 1 = 0, so the loop continues
        i--; // i is now zero, so the next loop iteration will cause a division by zero!
    }
```

So you need to do:

```
while(i > 0 && num % i == 0)
```

to make sure that `i` is never zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    unsigned int i=666, num;
    cout << "Enter number";
    cin >> num;
    while(i>1){
        i = num/2;
```

Why do you initiliaze i with 666 and then immediately assign `i=num/2`

By the way, "that inputs a number and outputs the highest divisor of it and then the highest divisor of the divisor and so on" seems like a good candidate for a recursive algorithm.

Comment: The debugger went wrong on the first "while" loop because "i" was undefined so I just defined it to a random (actualy not) value bigger than 1, I could have used a "do" loop as well.